STM32f4 TIM2 and TIM5 work but other timers do not
I am using STM32F4 and I am trying to create 8 independent pulse outputs. I have chosen 8 timers looking at the STM32F4 Discovery datasheet and mapped them to pins. I have code for TIM2 and TIM5 that works perfectly. I change the pulse and the frequency of the signal changes. I use the exact same code for the other timers except modified for the new timer, but these other timers once started just oscillate at a constant frequency regardless of what I set as the pulse.
int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();

    SystemClock_Config(SYS_CLOCK_FREQ_48_MHZ);

    uint32_t clk_freq = Get_PCLK1TIM();

    UART2_Init();

    while (1)
    {
        HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &recvd_data, 1);

        if (reception_complete == TRUE){
            Decode_MODBUS();
        }

        //  Check and see if there has been any updates to the register values
        for(uint8_t motor = 0; motor < NUM_MOTORS; motor++) {

            if (reg_changed[motor])
            {
                // pulse = clk_spd * (1 /(2*freq))
                double pulse_freq_float = (double)registers[motor];
                double pulse_float = ((double)clk_freq * (double)pump_speed_scale_factor) / (4.0 * pulse_freq_float); // 4 comes from (prescalar + 1) * 2 ... 2 for rising/falling edge
                pulse[motor] = (uint32_t)pulse_float;

                // Initialize the timer based on the frequency given by the user
                switch(motor) {

                    case 0:
                        TIMER5_Init();
                        //Start the timer
                        if(HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htimer5, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
                        {
                            Error_handler();
                        }
                        reg_changed[motor] = FALSE;
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        TIMER2_Init();
                        //Start the timer
                        if(HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htimer2, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
                        {
                            Error_handler();
                        }
                        reg_changed[motor] = FALSE;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        TIMER3_Init();
                        //Start the timer
                        if(HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htimer3, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
                        {
                            Error_handler();
                        }
                        reg_changed[motor] = FALSE;
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        TIMER14_Init();
                        //Start the timer
                        if(HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htimer14, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
                        {
                            Error_handler();
                        }
                        reg_changed[motor] = FALSE;
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        TIMER1_Init();
                        //Start the timer
                        if(HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htimer1, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
                        {
                            Error_handler();
                        }
                        reg_changed[motor] = FALSE;
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        TIMER4_Init();
                        //Start the timer
                        if(HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htimer4, TIM_CHANNEL_3) != HAL_OK)
                        {
                            Error_handler();
                        }
                        reg_changed[motor] = FALSE;
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        TIMER11_Init();
                        //Start the timer
                        if(HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htimer11, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
                        {
                            Error_handler();
                        }
                        reg_changed[motor] = FALSE;
                        break;

                    case 7:
                        TIMER9_Init();
                        //Start the timer
                        if(HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htimer9, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
                        {
                            Error_handler();
                        }
                        reg_changed[motor] = FALSE;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void TIMER5_Init()
{
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef tim5OC_init;
    htimer5.Instance = TIM5;
    htimer5.Init.Period = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    htimer5.Init.Prescaler = 1;
    if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htimer5) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }

    tim5OC_init.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE;
    tim5OC_init.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    tim5OC_init.Pulse  = pulse[0];
    if(HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htimer5,&tim5OC_init,TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }
}

void TIMER2_Init()
{
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef tim2OC_init;
    htimer2.Instance = TIM2;
    htimer2.Init.Period = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    htimer2.Init.Prescaler = 1;
    if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htimer2) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }

    tim2OC_init.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE;
    tim2OC_init.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    tim2OC_init.Pulse  = pulse[1];
    if(HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htimer2,&tim2OC_init,TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }
}

void TIMER3_Init()
{
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef tim3OC_init;
    htimer3.Instance = TIM3;
    htimer3.Init.Period = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    htimer3.Init.Prescaler = 1;
    if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htimer3) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }

    tim3OC_init.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE;
    tim3OC_init.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    tim3OC_init.Pulse  = pulse[2];
    if(HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htimer3,&tim3OC_init,TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }
}

void TIMER14_Init()
{
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef tim14OC_init;
    htimer14.Instance = TIM14;
    htimer14.Init.Period = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    htimer14.Init.Prescaler = 1;
    if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htimer14) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }

    tim14OC_init.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE;
    tim14OC_init.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    tim14OC_init.Pulse  = pulse[3];
    if(HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htimer14,&tim14OC_init,TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }
}

void TIMER1_Init()
{
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef tim1OC_init;

    // Enable the Main Output (required for advanced timers)
    TIM1->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E_Msk;
    TIM1->BDTR |= TIM_BDTR_MOE;
    TIM1->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;

    htimer1.Instance = TIM1;
    htimer1.Init.Period = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    htimer1.Init.Prescaler = 1;
    if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htimer1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }

    tim1OC_init.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE;
    tim1OC_init.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    tim1OC_init.Pulse  = pulse[4];



    if(HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htimer1,&tim1OC_init,TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }
}

void TIMER4_Init()
{
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef tim4OC_init;
    htimer4.Instance = TIM4;
    htimer4.Init.Period = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    htimer4.Init.Prescaler = 1;
    if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htimer4) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }

    tim4OC_init.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE;
    tim4OC_init.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    tim4OC_init.Pulse  = pulse[5];
    if(HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htimer4,&tim4OC_init,TIM_CHANNEL_3) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }
}

void TIMER11_Init()
{
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef tim11OC_init;
    htimer11.Instance = TIM11;
    htimer11.Init.Period = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    htimer11.Init.Prescaler = 1;
    if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htimer11) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }

    tim11OC_init.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE;
    tim11OC_init.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    tim11OC_init.Pulse  = pulse[6];
    if(HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htimer11,&tim11OC_init,TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }
}

void TIMER9_Init()
{
    TIM_OC_InitTypeDef tim9OC_init;
    htimer9.Instance = TIM9;
    htimer9.Init.Period = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    htimer9.Init.Prescaler = 1;
    if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htimer9) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }

    tim9OC_init.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE;
    tim9OC_init.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    tim9OC_init.Pulse  = pulse[7];
    if(HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htimer9,&tim9OC_init,TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_handler();
    }
}


void HAL_TIM_OC_DelayElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{

    /* TIM2_CH2 toggling with frequency = 500 Hz */
    TIM_TypeDef *timer = htim->Instance;

    if (timer == TIM5)
    {
        if(htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_2)
        {
            ccr_content = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim,TIM_CHANNEL_2);
            __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(htim,TIM_CHANNEL_2,ccr_content+pulse[0]);
        }
    }
    else if (timer == TIM2)
    {
        if(htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1)
        {
            ccr_content = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim,TIM_CHANNEL_1);
            __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(htim,TIM_CHANNEL_1,ccr_content+pulse[1]);
        }
    }
    else if (timer == TIM3)
    {
        if(htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1)
        {
            ccr_content = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim,TIM_CHANNEL_1);
            __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(htim,TIM_CHANNEL_1,ccr_content+pulse[2]);
        }
    }
    else if (timer == TIM14)
    {
        if(htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1)
        {
            ccr_content = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim,TIM_CHANNEL_1);
            __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(htim,TIM_CHANNEL_1,ccr_content+pulse[3]);
        }
    }
    else if (timer == TIM1)
    {
        if(htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1)
        {
            // for some unknown reason can't use the AF mode for advanced timers
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8);
        }
    }
    else if (timer == TIM4)
    {
        if(htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_3)
        {
            ccr_content = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim,TIM_CHANNEL_3);
            __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(htim,TIM_CHANNEL_3,ccr_content+pulse[5]);
        }
    }
    else if (timer == TIM11)
    {
        if(htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1)
        {
            ccr_content = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim,TIM_CHANNEL_1);
            __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(htim,TIM_CHANNEL_1,ccr_content+pulse[6]);
        }
    }
    else if (timer == TIM9)
    {
        if(htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1)
        {
            ccr_content = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(htim,TIM_CHANNEL_1);
            __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(htim,TIM_CHANNEL_1,ccr_content+pulse[7]);
        }
    }
}

void HAL_TIM_OC_MspInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef tim5OC_ch_gpios;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef tim2OC_ch_gpios;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef tim3OC_ch_gpios;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef tim14OC_ch_gpios;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef tim1OC_ch_gpios;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef tim4OC_ch_gpios;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef tim11OC_ch_gpios;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef tim9OC_ch_gpios;

    //1. enable the peripheral clock for the timer2 peripheral
    __HAL_RCC_TIM5_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_TIM2_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_TIM3_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_TIM14_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_TIM1_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_TIM4_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_TIM11_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_TIM9_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();

    //2. Configure gpios to behave as timer2 channel 1,2,3 and 4
    // PA1 --> TIM2_CH2

    tim5OC_ch_gpios.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
    tim5OC_ch_gpios.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    tim5OC_ch_gpios.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    tim5OC_ch_gpios.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    tim5OC_ch_gpios.Alternate = GPIO_AF2_TIM5;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &tim5OC_ch_gpios);

    tim2OC_ch_gpios.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    tim2OC_ch_gpios.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    tim2OC_ch_gpios.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    tim2OC_ch_gpios.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    tim2OC_ch_gpios.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_TIM2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &tim2OC_ch_gpios);

    tim3OC_ch_gpios.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
    tim3OC_ch_gpios.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    tim3OC_ch_gpios.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    tim3OC_ch_gpios.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    tim3OC_ch_gpios.Alternate = GPIO_AF2_TIM3;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &tim3OC_ch_gpios);

    tim14OC_ch_gpios.Pin = GPIO_PIN_7;
    tim14OC_ch_gpios.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    tim14OC_ch_gpios.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    tim14OC_ch_gpios.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    tim14OC_ch_gpios.Alternate = GPIO_AF9_TIM14;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &tim14OC_ch_gpios);

    tim1OC_ch_gpios.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
    tim1OC_ch_gpios.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    tim1OC_ch_gpios.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    tim1OC_ch_gpios.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &tim1OC_ch_gpios);

    tim4OC_ch_gpios.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
    tim4OC_ch_gpios.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    tim4OC_ch_gpios.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    tim4OC_ch_gpios.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    tim4OC_ch_gpios.Alternate = GPIO_AF2_TIM4;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &tim4OC_ch_gpios);

    tim11OC_ch_gpios.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
    tim11OC_ch_gpios.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    tim11OC_ch_gpios.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    tim11OC_ch_gpios.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    tim11OC_ch_gpios.Alternate = GPIO_AF3_TIM11;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &tim11OC_ch_gpios);

    tim9OC_ch_gpios.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    tim9OC_ch_gpios.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    tim9OC_ch_gpios.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    tim9OC_ch_gpios.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    tim9OC_ch_gpios.Alternate = GPIO_AF3_TIM9;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &tim9OC_ch_gpios);


    //3. nvic settings
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM5_IRQn,15,0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM5_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn,15,0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM3_IRQn,15,0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM3_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM8_TRG_COM_TIM14_IRQn,15,0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM8_TRG_COM_TIM14_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM1_CC_IRQn,15,0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM1_CC_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM4_IRQn,15,0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM4_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQn,15,0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM1_BRK_TIM9_IRQn,15,0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM1_BRK_TIM9_IRQn);
}


Things like this TIM_OC_InitTypeDef tim9OC_init; don't initialise the structure to anything. They exist on the stack and will be full of garbage values. Any field you don't explicitly set will contain garbage. Initialise them instead like so: TIM_OC_InitTypeDef tim9OC_init = {0};

You said other timers start oscillating. Do they oscillate with initial conditions? If so, it could be something in functions that change pulse duration and frequency.
